# APEX Authorization at PL/SQL level

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm developing an application in APEX and ran into an authorization problem that I hope someone could help me solve.

How can I apply authorization schemes at the SQL level in APEX?
For example, is it possible to create a report on a SQL query where the query returns different columns based on an authorization scheme defined in APEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to check whether the current user has a given authorization in PL/SQL, but not in SQL.

In Apex 5 and later:

```
if apex_authorization.is_authorized ('AUTH_GROUP') then ...
```

For Apex 4.2 and earlier:

```
if apex_util.public_check_authorization ('AUTH_GROUP') then ...
```

It returns a boolean so you can't use it in SQL.

Comment: Thank you. One further question: if I wanted to return a different SQL query depending on authorization scheme, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: One way: select stuff from table where auth_wrapper(scheme) = 'Y' union all select stuff from another_table where auth_wrapper(another_scheme) = 'Y'